# Unable to resolve symbol: new-map in this context in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I was searching and was not able to find the answer to my question.

I'm reading [Clojure For The Brave and True](https://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/) and found the implementation of the map over map values.

```clj
(reduce (fn [new-map [key val]]
          (assoc new-map key (inc val)))
        {}
        {:max 30 :min 10})
```

which works fine, except it throws an error in both REPL and file:

> java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: new-map in this context

when executed inside a function:

```clj
(defn map-map [fn hash]
  (reduce (fn [new-map [key val]]
            (assoc new-map key (inc val)))
          {}
          hash))
```

My own implementation (after reading 3rd chapter) works fine:

```clj
(defn map-map [fn hash]
  (into {} (map #(conj [(first %)] (fn (second %))) hash)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I've shadowed the `fn` with an argument. new-map is no longer a parameter in an anonymous function, and Clojure tries to evaluate it as the value in a vector that is passed to function `fn`.

```clj
(defn map-map [func hash]
  (reduce (fn [new-map [key val]]
            (assoc new-map key (func val)))
          {}
          hash))
```

Silly mistake, I'm adding this answer just in case someone will have the same error, and I've already taken the time to create a question.

This was the first step as you can see there is `inc` in the original code that I didn't yet replace with fn, because of a compiler error even in REPL.

Also, the problem was that my first implementation of `map-map` didn't use the `fn` macro so I could use it as a function.

Comment: You'll often see f used for an argument that is intended to be a function (or function-like thing). See https://guide.clojure.style/#idiomatic-names for other examples (many of which are single-character names)

Comment: I will often use the suffix `-fn` on a descriptive name (eg `tx-fn` since it transforms the original values). I like it a little better than a simple `f` as it jumps out of the text more than the 1-char `f`. Also, it is easier to search for in the editor or with `grep` (more unique => fewer false alarms).